# Keydown Event Listener does not listen

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm making a virtual keyboard, where by pressing a physical key, its replica must highlight on the screen. The thing is, that absolutely nothing happens, when I hit the button. The program listens to the mouse event, this part is fine. Code extraction:

```
_createKeys() {
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        const layout = [
            '`', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=', 'backspace',
            'tab', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '[', ']',
            'caps lock', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', ';', '\'', '\\', 'enter',
            'shiftLeft', '\\', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ',', '.', '/', 'shiftRight', 'arrowUp',
            'Ctrl', 'Win', 'Alt', 'space', 'Alt', 'Ctrl', 'arrowLeft', 'arrowDown', 'arrowRight'
        ];

        const createIconHTML = (icon_name) => {
            return `<i class="material-icons">${icon_name}</i>`;
        };

        layout.forEach(key => {
            const keyElement = document.createElement('button');
            const lineBreak = ['backspace', ']', 'enter', 'arrowUp'].indexOf(key) !== -1;
            keyElement.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            keyElement.classList.add('key');
            switch(key) {
                case 'caps lock':
                    keyElement.classList.add('key-wide');
                    keyElement.textContent = 'CapsLock';
                    keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this._toggleCapsLock();
                        keyElement.classList.toggle('key-caps', this.properties.capsLock);
                    });
                    keyElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
                        if(e.key === 'CapsLock') console.log('pressed');
                    });
             }
            fragment.appendChild(keyElement);
            if (lineBreak) {
                fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            }
        });
        return fragment;
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the `keydown` event listener to the `document` not `keyElement` otherwise the event will only fire if the element has the focus, which it definitely won't if the cursor is in a text field somewhere else in the page.

Instead of :

```
keyElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'CapsLock') console.log('pressed');
});
```

Use :

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'CapsLock') console.log('pressed');
});
```

However, adding ~100+ event listeners to `document` would not be a good idea. You should create a single event listener on `document` that listens for all keydown events and activates the appropriate virtual key.

```
layout.forEach(key => {
  ...
  keyElement.dataset.key = encodeURIComponent(key);
  ...
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  let k = encodeURIComponent(event.key);
  let vkey = document.querySelector(`[data-key="${k}"]`);
  vkey?.classList.add('pressed');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work with numeric keystrokes and punctuation marks. E.g. for js `([data-key= 1 ])` is not acceptable. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Using quotes around the value would probably be sufficient for numbers, but punctuation might still give you trouble. In that case, it would be best to encode the value. I'll update my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

you only call the `addEventListener` inside the switch case also to `document` not the element, which happens only with caps, so this needs to get out.
also, since it's only one `switch` `case`, why won't you use if condition instead? would make the code more readable for you.

Comment: It's just an extraction, there a lot more keys, I didn't write them here for clarity. What do you mean by "get out"?

Comment: "inside" the `switch` is a code that would only run if the condition happened, which is `key === 'caps lock'`, so for all the other keys clicked, the code won't even go inside the switch case, so it would never even call the `addEventListener` function
if it's still not clear maybe a quick screen share might help

Comment: Yes, please :D it doesn't work and without condition, e.g. `keyElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {console.log(e.key)});`